# Camera Intent returns no file path

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I have a problem with my camera Intent. It saves the pictures to the storage, but it doesn't return the file path to my activity. When i remove the EXTRA_OUTPUT it returns the file path, but then the images have just a very small size. Is there any solution to get the pictures with original size without using EXTRA_OUTPUT?

Here is my code:

```
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {     
     case R.id.btnImageCapture:
       preinsertedUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, preinsertedUri);
         startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_CAMERA);
       break;
       }
    }
```

---

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     switch(requestCode){
     case OPEN_CAMERA:
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                  Uri imageUri = null;
                  imageUri = data.getData();
                 if(imageUri == null && preinsertedUri != null){
                  imageUri = preinsertedUri;
                 }
                  String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                  int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                  cursor.moveToFirst();
                  filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                try {
                 Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                 ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                         File f = new File(filePath);
                         f.createNewFile();
                         FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                         fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                         fo.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 break;
          } 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you.

When I capture the photo from camera so I implement a logic using Cursor and iterate the cursor and get the last photo path which is capture from camera.

It give the path of last capture photo from camera.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Media.DATA, Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do {
        uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
        photoPath = uri.toString();
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: How comes its possible i tested in many devices this try to implement in right manner this logic.

Comment: @g.r. Why have you unaccept answer again after one day. Is there any wrong in this.

Comment: I found out the code has a very strange behavior. When i downloaded a picture with the browser and then tried to use this code it always imported the path of the picture that i downloaded with the browser. Currently the code isn't working at all and I don't know why. I didn't make any changes to it or to anything relevant to this code.

Comment: It seems that the pictures that i take with the camera Intent are completely ignored for some reason. Now i took a picture with the camera app and then the camera intent only took the file path of that picture.

Comment: why iterate through the entire cursor just to get the last element?? how about 'code' if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToLast()) 'code' and remove entire do..loop